# 1).why $U(\mathbf{x}, \epsilon)$ is open in box product, ? 2) why $U(\mathbf{x}, \epsilon)$ not open in the uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology

> Given $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots) \in \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ and given $0 < \epsilon < 1$, let $$U(\mathbf{x,\epsilon}) = (x_1 - \epsilon, x_1 + \epsilon) \times \cdots \times (x_n - \epsilon, x_n + \epsilon) \times \cdots.$$

My  Question  is  that

1).why $U(\mathbf{x}, \epsilon)$ is open in box product, ?

2) why $U(\mathbf{x}, \epsilon)$ is  not  open in the uniform topology ?

I see the munkre topology book page no. 124 section 20  ,,,as Munkre  have not  exaplain this in detail, as  im very confused now ..

so I need  detail  exaplanation  ....with simple language...

Thanks  u

Comment: The explanation on p 124 Munkres is about the product topology and the product metric in my edition. Not relevant to the box topology.

Comment: i mean  Theorem 20.4: The uniform topology on$ R^J$ is finer than the product topology and coarser than the box topology; these three topologies are all different if J is infinite.....

Comment: In my edition this is theorem 9.4 on p 122, but only for the product topology and the uniform topology. I have an old edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U(\mathbf{x},\varepsilon)$ is open in the box topology, because each set $(x_i - \varepsilon, x_i + \varepsilon)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and so $U(\mathbf{x},\varepsilon)$ is a product of infinitely many open sets and so a basic open set in the definition of the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. So in particular it's open in the box topology.

Now define $p_i = x_i + (1-\frac{1}{2^i})\varepsilon$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$. Note that $p_i \in (x_i - \varepsilon, x_i + \varepsilon)$, for all $i$, and thus $\mathbf{p} \in U(\mathbf{x},\varepsilon)$, as $p_i < x_i + \varepsilon$, but also note that $p_i$ gets closer and closer to the boundary of the set, as $i$ increases.

The claim is that $\mathbf{p} = (p_1, p_2, \ldots)$ is not an interior point of $U(\mathbf{x},\varepsilon)$ in the uniform metric topology. Suppose it were:
then there would be an $r>0$ (and we can also assume $r<1$ WLOG) such that $$B(\mathbf{p},r) \subseteq U(\mathbf{x},\varepsilon)$$

where the ball is taken in the uniform metric.

Now, define $p'_i = p_i + \frac{r}{2}$. Then $|p'_i - p_i| = \frac{r}{2}< 1$, so that $d= \sup_i \min(|p'_i - p_i|, 1) = \frac{r}{2} < r$, and thus $\mathbf{p'} = (p'_1, p'_2, \ldots,) \in B(\mathbf{p}, r)$.

But if we pick $i$ so large that $\frac{1}{2^i}\varepsilon < \frac{r}{2}$, then $$p'_i = p_i + \frac{r}{2} = x_i + \varepsilon(1-\frac{1}{2^i}) + \frac{r}{2} = x_i + \varepsilon + (\frac{r}{2} - \frac{1}{2^i}\varepsilon) > x_i + \varepsilon$$ and so $p'_i \notin (x_i - \varepsilon, x_i + \varepsilon)$ and we see that $\mathbf{p'} \notin U(\mathbf{x},\varepsilon)$, contradicting the above inclusion we were supposed to have. So indeed $\mathbf{p}$ is not an interior point of $U(\mathbf{x},\varepsilon)$.

Comment: thanks u so much @Henno sir   as  i found  ur explanation  very nice   and  more better  than Brian M scott  .....as   i  was reading the  Brian M. scott..his  way  of explaination is not easy...and also very difficult to understand...

Comment: @1TOPLOGY I usually find Brian's explanations quite clear. What posting of his are you referring too?

Comment: He(Brian)   has  gave the solution but  could not understand  its
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71546/the-uniform-metric-on-mathbbr-omega

Comment: As im not talking about particular post,,,as  i have  reads  many   solution Both of  u  and Brian M scott,,,,but personallyy  I  found  ur answer /explaination very useful/simple ,,feel its,,,and also easy to understands...